# ruby restclient default timeout

Tags: ruby, timeout

I was looking through the RestClient library, and trying to find the default timeout values. In v1.6.7, I see only a `open_timeout` and a `timeout`, but they seem to be only available within the library itself.

Looking through the library code, I am unable to determine what the default values are for these timeouts, nor was I able to figure out how to debug and have it spit out these values. Anyone know how I can get the library to output what these values are?

Part of my issue is most likely due to my beginner knowledge of Ruby, apologies!

Comment: About which exactly library are your talking about? (url would be helpful)

Comment: I'm using the Ruby gems. I think this is what I'm referring to:
https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/tree/v1.6.7
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#timeouts):

> By default the timeout for a request is 60 seconds.

I only had a quick look at the source but I suspect the timeout value comes from Net::HTTP on which it depends rather than RestClient.